# How to verify if a pthread function began execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, testing, pthreads, execution

Example:

```
void start(void)
{
   pthread_create(&threadID, Null, run_thread_function,arguments);

   //is there a way to ensure if the run_thread_function(basically new thread) started   
   //execution before returning from this(start) function    

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the return code.

```
if ((retcode = pthread_create(&threadID, Null, run_thread_function,arguments)) != 0)
{
   //something went wrong
}
```

Comment: Does that actually achieve what the OP asked for?

Comment: @Martin James - If OP means did the thread start or attempt to start, yes.  If he means did it get scheduled and execute, no.  Maybe the POSIX lawyers know of some guarantee but AFAIK you are at the whim of the scheduler at that point.  If OP is really looking wait on some condition then your answer is more appropriate.

Comment: yes, the above statement/check just guarantees the creation of a thread but not its execution ! And i am interested in the latter

Answer (score 4):

Pass a synchro object, (condvar, event or semaphore), as part of the arguments. Wait on it after calling pthread_create().  In the thread, signal it in the first line, (or after the thread has performed its init stuff, if that's what you are trying to achieve).

Comment: You could also consider using a barrier.

Answer (score 3):

Check the return code of the `pthread_create` function for error.

Update some shared variable and test it from another thread. Remember to use synchronization primitives, like mutex when updating the shared variable.

Or to make simple test, print some message with the thread id, or some other kind of identifier.

Comment: I don't understand - if you are going to use OS synchro primitives (like mutex,but not mutex:), why bother with polling the shared var?  Why not signal some event/semaphore/condvar from the new thread?

Answer (score 0):

With C++11, creating a thread through an object of type `std::thread` won't return until the new thread has started.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pthread_barrier_wait` if you want to know for certain that your new thread has begun.

Though, I really question code that cares deeply about this. Seems like you're asking for race conditions.

Note that I should be checking for return values all over the place and I'm not for the sake of succinctness clarity. *sigh*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *newthread(void *vbarrier)
{
   pthread_barrier_t *barrier = static_cast<pthread_barrier_t *>(vbarrier);
   sleep(2);
   int err = pthread_barrier_wait(barrier);
   if ((err != 0) && (err != PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD)) {
      ::std::cerr << "Aiee! pthread_barrier_wait returned some sort of error!\n";
   } else {
      ::std::cerr << "I am the new thread!\n";
   }
   return 0;
}

int main()
{
   pthread_barrier_t barrier;
   pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, 2);
   pthread_t other;
   pthread_create(&other, NULL, newthread, &barrier);
   pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
   ::std::cerr << "Both I and the new thread reached the barrier.\n";
   pthread_join(other, NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

C++11 doesn't have barriers. But barriers can easily be simulated, to an extent, using condition variables:

```
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

void runthread(::std::mutex &m, ::std::condition_variable &v, bool &started)
{
   sleep(2);
   {
      ::std::unique_lock< ::std::mutex> lock(m);
      started = true;
      v.notify_one();
   }
   ::std::cerr << "I am the new thread!\n";
}

int main()
{
   ::std::mutex m;
   ::std::condition_variable v;
   bool started = false;
   ::std::thread newthread(runthread, ::std::ref(m), ::std::ref(v), ::std::ref(started));
   {
      ::std::unique_lock< ::std::mutex> lock(m);
      while (!started) {
         v.wait(lock);
      }
   }
   ::std::cerr << "Both I and the new thread are running.\n";
   newthread.join();
   return 0;
}
```